# Node.js - Module Version Mismatch on Linode Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, linode

I am trying to deploy a node app on Linode (Ubuntu 12.04) while following this guide from Node Knockout: http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/9300619913/countdown-to-ko-14-deploying-your-node-js-app-to

I have no problems running the server as root, but when trying to start the server as the "deploy" user using `sudo start node`, I get this error:

```
   /home/deploy/app/source/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:79
            throw e
                  ^
    Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1.
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at bindings (/home/deploy/app/source/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/$
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/app/source/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:1:$
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have tried recompiling bcrypt using `make clean` then `make` since I thought my module version was incompatible with my version of node (v0.8.18), but that does not seem to be the case since I can start the server as root with no problem. I feel as though the problem lies in how I set up the deploy user, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your bcrypt version seems to be old. The tutorial you use also seems old it uses node-v0.4.11. Try going to the bcrypt folder and doing `make clean && make`. If it shows same error then remove it build it again.

Comment: I assumed that would be the problem as well, but after rebuilding the module, I continue to get the error when using the "deploy" user. As root, the node server runs just fine.